# Calculating $\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\mathrm{d}x\frac{\exp(-x^2)}{x^2+1}$ with the Cauchy formula

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, contour-integration, cauchy-integral-formula

Chances are, I am missing something trivial here, but I ran into a problem when trying to calculate the following improper integral:

$$ I=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\mathrm{d}x\frac{\exp(-x^2)}{x^2+1} . $$

My approach was to treat it as a complex integral, and use the Cauchy formula:

$$ I'=\int_{\Gamma}\mathrm{d}z\frac{\exp(-z^2)}{z^2+1}=2\pi i \left(\frac{\exp(-z^2)}{z+i}\right)_{z=i}=\pi e , $$

where $\Gamma$ is a closed curve (with the usual infinite-radius semicircle on the upper half-plane, denoted as $\gamma$). We can partition $I'$ as

\begin{align*}
 I'=& I+\int_{\gamma}\mathrm{d}z\frac{\exp(-z^2)}{z^2+1}=
       \\=& I+\underbrace{\lim_{R\rightarrow\infty}\int_0^{2\pi}\mathrm{d}\phi
\frac{iR\exp(i\phi)\exp(-R^2\exp(i2\phi))}{R^2\exp(i2\phi)+1}}_{=0}\\
   =&I .
\end{align*}

Based on this, $I=\pi e$. However, the actual answer should be

$$ I=\pi e (1-\mathrm{erf}(1)) . $$

It seems as if I missed a $\pi e\mathrm{erf}(1)$ term on the right hand side, but I cannot see how...

I know the integral is evaluated in [this SE post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2913682/evaluating-the-integral-int-0-infty-frac-exp-u21u2-du). But I would be grateful if someone could correct my Cauchy formula-based reasoning, if possible.

Comment: From what I see, $\exp\Big(-R^2\exp(\text{i}2\phi)\Big)$ can be exponentially big, so the claim that the limit as $R\to \infty$ of its integral being zero is most likely untrue.  I think a better way to solve the problem is to note that the function $J:\mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}\to \mathbb{R}$ defined by $$J(a):=\int_{\mathbb{R}}\,\frac{\exp(-ax^2)}{x^2+1}\,\text{d}x$$ for every $a\geq 0$ satisfies $$J(a)-J'(a)=\int_{\mathbb{R}}\,\exp(-ax^2)\,\text{d}x,$$ with $J(0)=\pi$.  Of course, $J(1)=I$.

Comment: Related: [Methods to solve $\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-x^2}}{x^2 + 1}\:dx$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3042183/631742) and [On $\int_0^\infty \frac{\exp(-x^2)}{1+x^2}dx=\frac{\pi e}2\text{erfc}(1)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3043256/) and [Evaluating the integral $\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\exp(-u^2)}{1+u^2} \, du$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2913682/)